# Remove all storage file in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am need to clear all my `storage` files , I am try this :

```
Route::get('/clear/storage', function () {
        $file = new Filesystem;
        $file->cleanDirectory('storage/app');
        return show_message(true, 'clear successfully');
});
```

and this is my storage :

[image]

how could I do that to clear all fills ?

Comment: `$file->cleanDirectory` should work. Is there an error you're getting? Please provide that as well.

Comment: @ zlatan no there is not error ,and the successful message show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

Route::get('/clear/storage', function () {
    File::cleanDirectory(storage_path('/'));
    return show_message(true, 'clear successfully');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
$getAllFilesInPath = scandir('storage/app');
Storage::delete($getAllFilesInPath);
```